# Limit users to their own resources (URL mangling)

Tags: node.js, express, vuejs2

I'm building a SPA with vue and node.js / express.js . At this moment I dont have any way to limit different users to access resources from other users by just modifying the id part in one of my urls. Example:

```
'/api/v1/house/:id/pets'
```

I have other end points that follow these rules too. I know I could create a middle-ware for every resource type and add it to express routes. Something like:

```
app.get('/api/v1/house/:id/pets', userOwnsHouseMiddleware, appsConfig.getPetsInHouse);
```

Is this a good way to accomplish this? Could I build a more generic (not resource dependant) middleware?

Comment: Use JWT (Json Web Tokens) to authorize requests and ensure users can only access their own resources.

Comment: If your DB's documents/rows refer to the user with a standard name (e.g. `user_id`), then you can make the middleware more generic. But in some cases where the user is not directly on the entity (pets might be pointing to a house, which in turn points to a user, and you may want a `/pets` endpoint, without houses involved), this middleware would need a "path" parameter to know what entities to retrieve in what order, so that it matches a user. Something like `app.get('/collars', getValidationMiddleware([{pets: 'pet_id'}, {houses: 'house_id'}])`. But beware of performance with too many joins...